# Use numpy arrays to count similar tuples

Tags: python, numpy

I have 32 arrays like this one::

```
>>> d01
array([[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
       [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

>>> d02 ...

>>> d32
array([[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
       [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

- they have only ones in line 3, dxy[2, i] = 1
- pairs (dxy[0, i], res[1, i]) are uniques
- the typical dxy.shape ~(3, 10e6)
- the 32 dxy arrays can't be a dict because they're on shared memory.

What is the fastest way that scale up onto memory to get this final structure::

```
>>> res
array([[8, 8, 7, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3],
       [6, 2, 8, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]])
```

So the value of res[2, i] represent the number of times the tuple (res[0, i], res[1, i]) exist in the 32 dxy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Counter container, which is a boosted dictionnary (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)).

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

d01 = np.array([[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
       [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

d02 = np.array([[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
       [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Build the counter:

```
count = Counter(map(tuple,np.c_[d01,d02][:2].T.tolist()))

Out[1]:
Counter({(0, 2): 1,
         (0, 5): 2,
         (1, 5): 2,
         (3, 2): 1,
         (4, 8): 1,
         (7, 8): 1,
         (8, 2): 1,
         (8, 6): 1})
```

Reformatting the counter as matrix:

```
res = np.c_[np.array(list(count.keys())),list(count.values())].T
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 8, 7, 0],
       [5, 2, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 2],
       [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```